# Contact form 7 : Check wether one field is filled

Tags: php, validation, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a form build with Contact Form 7 where people could make a reservation for tickes and have the form send to a email address.  We have 2 kinds of tickets. 
So people could choose 1 quantity for ticket 1 and 0 for ticket 2.

Is it possible to code a validation that visitors should fill either a minimal amount of 1 for either ticket 1 or ticket 2?

Comment: Why don't you use select box?

Comment: @daniyalahmad select box does not guarantee user input the right value, and OP still need to verify which one is filled and verify its minimum value

Answer (score 0):

actually, you need to post sample code for people to help you, so that they don't guess around and made a completely irrelevant answer.

but then again, here are some premises (wild guess):

- you have two input boxes, with tiket1 and tiket2 as their names
- you using POST method

then you need to check for those variables in PHP by:

```
if ($_POST['tiket1'] > 0 or $_POST['tiket2'] > 0){
 // do valid action
} else {
 // show some errors
}
```

Comment: If you know Contact Form 7 for wordpress, you would know how it works.. no need to place the code I'm using.  I just have 2 number fields in the form and I want a conditional validation.